# How to use two fields as username in Django custom user model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I have employee table (legacy) with fields Employee_no, Company_name and Password. How can i use my current table as Django user model?
**Employee_no is duplicate but combination with company_name, it will be unique.**

I need to use employee_no and company_name as username to login.

| Employee_no | Company_name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | any password |
| 1 | Samsung | any password |
| 2 | Apple | any password |
| 3 | Samsung | any password |
| 3 | Google | any password |

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Example.It will be used in case or email or phone number

```
        try:
            user_obj = User.objects.get(Q(email=email_or_mobile) | Q(mobile_number=email_or_mobile))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception("Invalid email or mobile number")
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise Exception("Invalid password")
        if user_obj.is_active:
           login(request,user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django enforce you to have a unique `USERNAME_FIELD` in User model in order to use all the features that it provides out of the box. But you can always customize it if you really need it (with a little extra work).

In your situation you need a User model with two fields that uniqueness define them. This implies having a [Custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) and implementing your custom [Authentication Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django)

For User model you should have something like this:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    employee_no = models.IntergerField()
    company_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "employee_no"  # Not really used, but required by Django
    
    # Completes custom User subclassing ...

    class Meta:
        # This is required for your design in order to have database integrity
        unique_together = ('employe_no', 'company_name')
```

If your try to run server with this user model you will get System check errors

You should add to your settings

```py
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ["auth.E003", "auth.W004"]
```

Now you have to implement a custom auth backend in order to authenticate
users against two fields. For that just [subclass `django.contrib.auth.backends.BaseBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) and implement your authentication logic.

Something like this:

```py
class CustomBackend(BaseBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, employee_no=None, company_name=None, password=None, **kwargs):

        if employee_no is None or company_name is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(employee_no=employee_no, company_name=company_name)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

And add this backend to your settings in the list of `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` (dotted string path)

Finally you must ensure passing the right parameters in login view to authenticate method and be very carefull with other integrations that requires standar Django User model.